# A group of animals (missing)

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle

I'm looking for a three word phrase.

---

TIGER
NUMBAT
ALPACA
HORSE
PANDA
EAGLE
LAMB
ELK
DOLPHIN
RAT
ALLIGATOR
PELICAN
OSTRICH
EMU
LEMUR
OWL
LLAMA
ALBATROSS
FALCON
FOX
UAKARI
BEAR
NYALA
OCTOPUS
IGUANA
LEMMING
OTTER
NEEDLEFISH
IMPALA
HAMSTER
REINDEER

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the three-word answer is likely to be:

> **[THE BIG FIVE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_five_game)**

As...

> If you look at the first letters of the listed animals, from the bottom of the list to the top, you can read the names of five animals 'missing' from the list itself: **RHINO**, **LION**, **BUFFALO**, **LEOPARD**, and **ELEPHANT**.
>
>  Collectively (as a *group*), these animals are known as Africa's 'Big Five' game animals (specifically the black rhinoceros, African bush elephant, and African buffalo species), said by big-game hunters to be the five most difficult animals in Africa to catch on foot.

Comment: Lightning :) I just (wrongly) had a "The" in front of the two main words. Tick is yours!

Comment: @Prim3numbah Not wrongly at all - I'd say it's perfectly valid to use 'the' as the leading word, and in fact I think it sounds nicer that way - happy to tweak my answer :)